# Why can't I assign the value of the PID chunk of the FS register to an unsigned int?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Short description (32 bit build)

Why does this throw an improper operand error?

```
unsigned int GetPID() {

    unsigned int id;
    __asm {
        mov id, fs:[0x20];
    }
    return id;
```

but not this?

```
unsigned int GetPID() {

    unsigned int id;
    __asm {
        mov ebx, fs:[0x20];
        mov id, ebx;
    }
    return id;
}
```

I'm new to using assembly within C and I'd like some explanations on how things work when I use it.

Note. I know using this function to get the current process id is bad. This is just an experiment, im also learning about operating systems.

Side question: is it ok to write half of a function in assembly brackets? and then finish the function with C? or should every function be either all C or all assembly?

Comment: Because that's the way the processor works. In assembly you cannot move anything anywhere, there are strict rules. Every processor typo has different rules.

Comment: Ironic, @Jabberwocky: I think you mean "Every processor *type* has different rules."

Comment: @JohnBollinger too late for editing. indeed the _o_  in _typo_  is a typo ;-)

Comment: Just use the `GetCurrentProcessId` function. There's no need to use inline assembly or to play around with undocumented Windows internal structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Intel assembly doesn't support `MOV` from memory to memory. `id` is a memory location. You can only MOV from memory to a register or vice versa.

That said, check out the `__readfsdword` compiler intrinsic.

Answer (score 2):

but not this?   Because the register is being used to trampoline the value; without this trampoline, the opcode may be something like: movl -4[ebp], fs:[0x20].   You aren’t out of the woods yet -- ebx is a callee-preserved register in most implementations, so by corrupting it, you would trigger an error somewhere up the call stack.   Those are particularly nasty to debug, because all traces of GetPID may be gone (stack rewritten) before the corruption is detectable.

ok to write a function?:   my opinion is that all C or all assembly is the best: it is clearer and more maintainable.  Even with the gcc-constraints specification, inlining is a crapshoot between compiler versions and bugs within various versions.  Who wants that baked into your source?   An assembly module need only conform to the relevant ABI [ usually well published ], and provides a nice spot to say “ this is the machine dependent stuff “.

Comment: If you write conforming (and this is harder than it appears) inline assembly with GCC what kind of bugs are you referring to? Generally speaking the bugs are almost exclusively a misuse of inline assembly that lead to undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can manifest itself differently across compilers and compiler options. If you properly understand all the rules (and there are a lot) for GCC inline assembly it does work as expected.

Comment: I do prefer compiler intrinsics over external assembly or inline assembly when available. with MSVC I'd consider utilizing intrinsics like __readfsbyte, __readfsdword, __readfsqword, __readfsword if needing to reference data through the FS segment

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on ebx and the other tips. i didnt know that. im gonna read up more on x86

Comment: The rules for GCC inline assembly have changed over the years, particularly in pinning down what volatile means.   That isn't a slight against GCC, more against the standards group.  With LTO now inspecting the opcodes to determine the critical ordering, there could be another coming.   I recall some version of the ppc code generator requiring a fake 256 byte local variable to get it to believe that "memory" actually meant "memory".

Answer (score 0):

I found a long time ago that writing inline assmebly in `.c` files was essentially always a mistake. Rather than having a short list of obvious places you have to change when porting to a new processor, you end up with them scattered everywhere. I took the liberty of rewriting your function in a `.asm` file for you:

```
.486
.MODEL FLAT
.CODE
PUBLIC _GetPID
_GetPID PROC
    mov eax, fs:[0x20]
    ret
_GetPID ENDP
END
```